# How to resolve scheduler and controller-manager unhealthy state in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

## Symptom:

When we install the new kubernetes cluster. When we execute the following command:

```
$ kubectl get cs / kubectl get componentstatuses
```

we get this error:

```
Warning: v1 ComponentStatus is deprecated in v1.19+
NAME                 STATUS      MESSAGE                                                              ERROR
controller-manager   Unhealthy   Get "http://127.0.0.1:10252/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10252: connect: connection refused
scheduler            Unhealthy   Get "http://127.0.0.1:10251/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10251: connect: connection refused
etcd-0               Healthy     {"health":"true"}
```

Answer (score 39):

## Solution:

Modify the following files on all master nodes:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml
```

Clear the line (spec->containers->command) containing this phrase: - --port=0

```
$ sudo vi /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
```

Clear the line (spec->containers->command) containing this phrase: - --port=0

```
$ sudo systemctl restart kubelet.service
```

## Another reason for this problem:

You may have used http_proxy in the docker setting. In this case, you must set address of the master nodes addresses in no_proxy

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Couldn't get any other solid fix other than this!