# kubernetes pod's probe failed - Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers

Tags: kubernetes

I've searched but nothing has helped me through.

My Set.
k8s - v1.20.2.
calico - 3.16.6.
pod-cidr = 10.214.0.0/16.
service-cidr = 10.215.0.1/16.

Installed by kubespray with this one https://kubernetes.io/ko/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubespray

[pod restarts again and again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w7WH.png).
[ingress-nginx-controller pod describe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABvUf.png)

[dns-autoscaler pod logs]

```
github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cluster-proportional-autoscaler/pkg/autoscaler/k8sclient/k8sclient.go:96: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.215.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 10.215.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

[dns-autoscaler pod describe]

```
kubelet  Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.214.116.129:8080/healthz": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

[coredns pod logs]

```
pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get "https://10.215.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.215.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

[coredns pod describe]

```
Get "http://10.214.122.1:8080/health": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

And I tried to install ingress-nginx-controller it got me logs and describe.
[ingress-controller logs]

```
W0106 04:17:16.715661       6 flags.go:243] SSL certificate chain completion is disabled (--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false)
W0106 04:17:16.715911       6 client_config.go:541] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0106 04:17:16.716200       6 main.go:182] Creating API client for https://10.215.0.1:
```

[ingress-controller describe]

```
Liveness probe failed: Get "https://10.214.233.2:8443/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

All those pods are struggling with Readiness/Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.214.116.155:10254/healthz": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).

Calico is Running. and i checked pod to pod communication(OK).
[calico is Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir5w3.png)

[kubectl get componentstatuses]

```
controller-manager   Unhealthy   Get "http://127.0.0.1:10252/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10252: connect: connection refused
scheduler            Unhealthy   Get "http://127.0.0.1:10251/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10251: connect: connection refused
etcd-1               Healthy     {"health":"true"}
etcd-2               Healthy     {"health":"true"}
etcd-0               Healthy     {"health":"true"}
```

[kubectl get componentstatuses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtoJ3.png)
I followed [How to resolve scheduler and controller-manager unhealthy state in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296491/how-to-resolve-scheduler-and-controller-manager-unhealthy-state-in-kubernetes)
and now scheduler and controller-manager are healthy.

[kubectl get nodes]

```
Nodes are ready.
```

what i did wrong? T.T.
thanks in advance

Comment: Your calico network is not working. Use this [tool](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/getting-started/clis/calicoctl/install) and [confirm it](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/reference/calicoctl/node/status).

Comment: @gohm'c Thanks. but Calico is running. I just put image on the issue

Comment: A wired thing is I can't curl to a pod in node from the node. but i can curl to the pod from other nodes.

Comment: Can you post the output of "kubectl get componentstatuses"?

Comment: @gohm'c thanks I post the output

Comment: As you can see the core components are not working. Try "kubectl get nodes" and see if they are ready? If not, your calico network cannot be working.

Comment: @gohm'c thanks a lot! controller-manager / scheduler are unhealthy but nodes are ready. I will follow this solution and will put the result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296491/how-to-resolve-scheduler-and-controller-manager-unhealthy-state-in-kubernetes

Comment: @gohm'c now controller-manager and scheduler are healthy but still above issue remains

Comment: @JovialCoding Please post your answer if the issue has been resolved so that it would be helpful for other community members for reference.

Comment: @AbhijithChitrapu i've been stucked in the problem.

Answer (score 14):

Experienced this issue when deploying an app to Kubernetes.

> Warning  Unhealthy  10m (x3206 over 3d16h)    kubelet  Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.2.0.97:80/": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

I did an exec into the pod:

```
kubectl exec <pod-name> -it --namespace default /bin/bash
```

And then I ran a curl request to the IP and port of the pod:

```
curl 10.2.0.97:80
```

And it returned a successful response. But the liveness probe was still failing to execute successfully.

**Here's how I solved it:**

All I had to do was to increase the `timeoutSeconds` to `10`:

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: http
  initialDelaySeconds: 300       
  periodSeconds: 20
  timeoutSeconds: 10
```

After which the liveness probe started executing successfully

Same can be done for the readiness probe:

```
ReadinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: http
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 20
  timeoutSeconds: 10
```

**Reference**: [Sometime Liveness/Readiness Probes fail because of net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting head](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/89898#issuecomment-1028654403)

Comment: Yes, in my case timeoutSeconds was an issue

Comment: Same here, timeoutSeconds was the issue! Thanks

Comment: I have a similar issue. I understand that increasing timeout of healthcheck can resolve it but I don't know how much increase is reasonable and what is real root cause?